# Can MSpec Test Adapter in Visual Studio run behaviours?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs, continuous-integration, mspec

I'm setting up continuous build in TFS 2013. The build has been configured to run MSpec tests by using the dlls in the [MSpec Test Adapter](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4abcb54b-53b5-4c44-877f-0397556c5c44). After much struggle it is working but the Test Adapter can't run MSpec behaviours. To be fair this isn't a TFS thing - if the tests are run through Visual Studio 2013  then they fail if they have behaviours. Without behaviours then they work just fine.

Has anyone else noticed this? Is this a know limitation on the MSpec Test Adapter or is there something I can do to get behaviours working?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you can do is check the source code of the adapter for behaviors. If there is no indication of them, contribute the code to make them work.

I haven't looked, but I doubt the adapter has support for this lesser known feature of mspec.